# "Expected a Type" error for protocol which should be known to the compiler

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, forward-declaration

Minimum Example "Test.h":

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

@protocol CallBack <NSObject>

-(void)method;

@end

@interface Test : NSObject

-(void)callback:(CallBack*)theCallback;

@end
```

And the corresponding "Test.m":

```
#import "Test.h"

@implementation Test

-(void)callback:(CallBack*)theCallback
{
    [theCallback method];
}
@end
```

This will give me a "Expected a Type" error for the CallBack parameter both in the .m and the .h file. As the CallBack protocol is defined before everything else, i can't see why the compiler can't find it. If i add a Forward-Definition @class CallBack; at the beginning of the header file it will give me a "Receiver type 'CallBack' for instance message is a forward declaration" error for the line [theCallback method].

why can't the compiler find the protocol?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The correct syntax to refer to an object that conforms to the `CallBack` protocol is `id<CallBack>`.

Thus, you might want:

```
@protocol CallBack <NSObject>

-(void)method;

@end

@interface Test : NSObject

-(void)callback:(id <CallBack>)theCallback;

@end
```

and

```
@implementation Test

-(void)callback:(id <CallBack>)theCallback
{
    [theCallback method];
}
@end
```

For more information, see [Working with Protocols](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/cocoa/conceptual/ProgrammingWithObjectiveC/WorkingwithProtocols/WorkingwithProtocols.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40011210-CH11-SW1) in the *Programming with Objective-C* guide.

Comment: Good answer. To extend it a bit: `id<CallBack>` means "any object that conforms to the `CallBack` protocol. You can also (unlike in some other OO languages) specify both class inheritance and protocol conformance in a type declaration: `NSArray <CallBack> *` means "any object whose class is (or inherits from) `NSArray` that also implements the `CallBack` protocol".

Comment: why is the * not needed when i'm using id? It's still a pointer, isn't it?

Comment: @user3005567 `id` is, by definition, a generic pointer to an object, so the `*` would be redundant. See the discussion of `id` down in this document: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/cocoa/conceptual/ProgrammingWithObjectiveC/WorkingwithObjects/WorkingwithObjects.html. BTW, you see this all the time in `init` methods that are generally defined as `- (id) init;` (i.e. a method that returns a pointer to an object) versus `-(NSString *) someString;` which explicitly returns a pointer to a string.